# How do I check if a variable is falsey in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to do something like this but it is invalid.

```
{{if ! notification}}
```

I am working on an old system and notification could be null, false or undefined. How do I check if this variable is falsey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`unless`](http://handlebarsjs.com/#unless) block helper which is the opposite of `if` block helper

```
{{#unless notification}}
    // Your content
{{/unless}}
```